# What are the "env" options (and their purpose) when creating a Java NIO filesystem?

Tags: java, filesystems, nio

There are lots of examples on the net about creating Java NIO Filesystem instances using code like this

```
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
    env.put("create", "true");

    FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipUri, env);
```

But what are the supported options that can be placed within the "env" map? And what are they good for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`FileSystem.newFileSystem(URI uri, Map<String,​?> env)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#newFileSystem(java.net.URI,java.util.Map)) specifies

> **env** - a map of provider specific properties to configure the file system; may be empty

So these depend on the type of provider that will create the new `FileSystem` for the given `uri`.

In your example, you've provided a `URI` presumably representing a ZIP file. This is served by a [Zip File System Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) whose properties are defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemproviderprops.html). Those are

- `"create"`: *`true` / `false`*

  > The value should be of type `java.lang.String`. The default value is `false`. If the value is `true`, the zip file system provider creates a new zip file if it does not exist.
- `"encoding"`: *`String` indicating the encoding scheme*

  > The value should be of type `java.lang.String`. The value of the property indicates the encoding scheme for the names of the entries in the zip or JAR file. The default value is UTF-8.